# Alexa app is unable to delete the smart home device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to delete the device from the alexa app. But I am keep on getting the message "Alexa was unable to remove this device. Please try again". These device were successfully added by my backend code.

I am looking for suggestions what could be the root cause.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Post the (relevant) code that tries to delete the device, along with the exact error messaage. Without any code it's impossible to know what's happening.

Comment: @Alejandro The backend is not deleting the device. I am trying to delete it from the Alexa app. There are somethings I need to understand do I need to write a DeleteReport at the backend side. Or is the Alexa app can directly delete the smart device also? Because currently I am trying to delete directly from the Alexa app from the trash icon.

Comment: Then it's not a programming question.

Comment: @Alejandro yes. But I need some hint why the Alexa app is not deleting? But anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you described is expected and as designed - in order to remove smart home devices discovered by your skill from a customer's account, you need to be able to proactively delete endpoints, as well as track when your skill is disabled by the customer.

If you want to proactively remove devices from the Alexa app using your smart home skill, you can use the DeleteReport event to specify endpoints have since been removed from the customer's account:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html#deletereport-event

If you want to track when a skill is disabled, you can subscribe to the SkillDisabled event to receive events in your endpoint:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-events-in-alexa-skills.html#skill-disabled-event

By combining the SkillDisabled event with the DeleteReport, you will be able to track when a skill is disabled - you can then use the DeleteReport to delete endpoints for the customer based on the customer ID.

Comment: I am actually deleting the device but it keeps on throwing an exception
Request failed with status code 500
The request also looks fine as per docs. But I do not have a clue how can I trace down this exception